# SSIS - Get data from db2, load into staging tables, and then merge into destination tables?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, db2

I'm working on an SSIS package to get data from a couple of db2 tables, and insert into preliminary tables. From there I need to merge that into the destination tables.

I'm having trouble as I don't understand why the *staging/preliminary* tables are necessary. Is there something that happens when merging from the staging tables to the destination table? Is it just a way to get rid of duplicate data?

Comment: Often times staging tables are used to allow for any data transformations or added static/calculated fields that need added to the data ahead of the merge process.  It also allows for a stepped approach that is easier and more efficient to recover from if there is a mid-process failure.  A lot of the 'required' aspect really depends on the specifics of the data in question.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Whats your destination? SQL Server, DB2, Oracle?